Table type that supports Multipage, Flexible width, Multiline text, vlines and hlines, Footnotes
I spent hours for looking for the table which supports all I need. Found longtblr which I thought supports everything but suddenly realized that it can't handle Footnotes. Maybe there is one I missed?

Welcome to TeX.SE! xltabular longtblr of tabularray package, longtable etc. For examples of their use search this tags ...
